# Install Search Engine plugin to FireFox from Extension

Tags: firefox-addon

I am developing a Firefox extension. I would like to install new search plugin to the firefox search bar. I tried 2 ways, but none of them seems to work 100%.

1. AddSearchEngineProvider works,
   but it displays "fail to install
   message" if the the search engine
   with the same name already exist. I
   dont see any API that enables me to
   query existing search engines.
2. In Mozilla Firefox\searchplugins
   I see xml files that represent the
   actual search plugins. I was able to
   add my search engine manually, but I
   dont really know how to add the xml
   file during the installation. I have
   XPI file, which has very limited
   abilities to access IO.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines should be put into the `searchplugins/` directory of your extension. They will be added automatically when your extension is installed - and removed again when it is uninstalled. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Bundles.